# How to print text from db in special template for specific page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have five pages and I have created a different layout for last two pages, that layout has a div with class infoDiv and that div has a text which I just put manually in the source code, so I can't change it through wordpress. How can I have it available in my dashboard so client no need to change in code?

```
            <?php

        /*
        Template Name: Special Layout    
         */

        get_header();

        if (have_posts()) {

            while (have_posts()) {
                the_post();
                ?>

                <article class="borderClass">
                    <h2> <?php the_title(); ?> </h2>

                    <div class="infoDiv">
                        <h4>This is info div</h4>
                        <p>this is the text I want to edit or add 
                          using dashboard.</p>

                    </div>


                   <?php the_content(); ?>
                </article>

                <?php
            }
        } else {
            echo "<p>No content found</p>";
        }

        get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move `<?php the_content(); ?>` like below

```
<article class="borderClass">

  <?php the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' ); ?>

  <div class="infoDiv">

    <?php the_content(); ?> <!-- Entered content -->

  </div>

</article>
```